# Isolating A matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know why these types of problems are causing my head to spin. But anyways...

Question:

Solve for $A$

$(A^{T}+4I)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}-1&5\\2&5\end{bmatrix}$

So, I proceeded to solve by doing:

$((A^{T}+4I)^{-1})^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}-1&5\\2&5\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$

$A^{T}+4I = \frac{-1}{15}\begin{bmatrix}5&-5\\-2&-1\end{bmatrix}$

Now I am at a loss, do I subtract $4I$ from both sides? Seems not because none of the answers that were listed resembled anything had I done this.

The possible answers are as follows:

A.) $\frac{1}{15}\begin{bmatrix}-40&2\\7&-44\end{bmatrix}$

B.) $\frac{1}{16}\begin{bmatrix}-30&2\\5&-34\end{bmatrix}$

C.) $\frac{1}{15}\begin{bmatrix}-30&2\\7&-44\end{bmatrix}$

D.) $\frac{1}{15}\begin{bmatrix}25&-2\\-5&43\end{bmatrix}$

E.) $\frac{1}{16}\begin{bmatrix}50&-2\\-6&34\end{bmatrix}$

F.) $\frac{1}{16}\begin{bmatrix}20&-2\\-5&44\end{bmatrix}$

G.) $\frac{1}{16}\begin{bmatrix}60&-2\\-6&39\end{bmatrix}$

H.) $\frac{1}{15}\begin{bmatrix}-65&2\\5&-59\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Yes you do. And then you go on with the rest.

Comment: I see the right answer there...

Comment: The last one seems promising

Answer (score 0):

You, you subtract $4\operatorname{Id}$ form both sides. And then you transpose the matrix that you got. The right answer is H), by the way.